# Приводит ли хранение ссылки на Application в static поле внутри себя к утечки памяти?

Tags: java, android, outofmemoryerror

Есть желание при запуске приложения хранить ссылку в переопределённом Application на саму себя в static поле для удобства доступа к актуальному контексту, конфигурации и id ресурсов.

**Насколько это критично для утечки памяти?**

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

/**
 * Название главных настроек
 */
private static final String SETTINGS_NAME = "erfecdcdvqefvwe";

//Для реализации ссылки на приложение
private static MainApplication instance;


/**
 * Стартует при зауске приложения
 */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Сохраняем ссылку на этот класс
    instance = this;
}


/**
 * Вернуть ссылку на приложение
 */
public static MainApplication getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Главные настройки приложения
 */
public static SharedPreferences getSettings(){
    return getInstance().getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static Context getAppContext(){
    return getInstance().getApplicationContext();
}

/**
 * Получить цвет из ресурсов
 */
public static ColorDrawable getResColor(int resId){
    return new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(MainApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), resId));
}


/**
 * Пиксели в DP
 */
public   static float dpFromPx(float px) {
    return px/ getAppContext()
            .getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics()
            .density;
}

/**
 * DP в пиксели
 */
public static float pxFromDp(float dp) {
    return dp * getAppContext()
            .getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics()
            .density;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не критично. `Application` живёт в течении всего приложения и умирает только когда умирает приложение. `Application` не может существовать в более чем одном экземпляре, а значит никаких утечек памяти быть не может.

Недостатком является то, что нет гарантии, что не статический `onCreate()` будет вызван до того, как какой-то статический код инициализации попытается получить ваш объект `Context`. Это означает, что ваш вызывающий код должен быть готов к работе с `null` значениями.

Тем не менее даже в серьезных проектах этот подход используется. И в целом это очень распространенное решение.

Comment: Я точно не уверен, но [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33241510/3212712) пишут, что Application один на один процесс. Если к-л сервис будет в другом процесс - будет ещё один экземпляр создан.

Comment: Да, но тогда этот процесс будет иметь свой контекст. Он будет жить точно так же нам весь процесс. В целом замечание верное. Но использовать его все равно можно

Answer (score 4):

Все хорошо, так делать можно, если есть потребность.

Извините, но я дам вам дополнительный callback по коду, в конце концов на то сообщества и нужны:

- класс **Application** должен быть пустым. Никаких статических методов общего назначиеня(dpFromPx, pxFromDpб getResColor) - выносите их в отдельный классы. В Application должны быть только инициализации синглтонов (за редким исключением, вроде Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler).
- переходите на Kotlin. Не вижу ни одной причины учиться писать под android на java. Kotlin не так сильно отличается от Java, чтобы его бояться. Это даст вам множество синтаксического сахара и полезного опыт разработки.
- пишите комментарии на английском. Кто бы не смотрел код после вас - точно поймет коментарии к коду, а заодно вы подтянете язык. Плюс, в какой бы среде или редакторе в будущем вы не откроете свой код латиница точно отобразиться верно.

Надеюсь, вы поизитвно относитесь к конструктивной критике.

Comment: Согласен с автором по поводу котлина за одним исключением: Java все равно нужна. Пока что без нее никуда, много легаси, много кода написанного на Java который надо понимать. Ну и перейти на котлин зная Java не сложно, а вот наоборот проблемно. Поэтому переходить стоит только если уверен в JAva

Comment: Я  не просто позитивно отношусь, я её ищу, что бы развиваться) Отдельное спасибо)

Comment: Вопрос по первому пункту, это для чистоты кода, или влияет на производительность?

Comment: Вопрос по второму, читал, что лучше начать с Java, да и с C# на неё перейти труда не составило и, конечно, побаиваюсь , что Kotlin это очередной продукт Google, который загнётся, или трансформируется до неузнаваемости. Ошибаюсь?

Comment: первый это строго чистота кода, но мы твердо знаем из практики, что в грязком коде о производительности говорить не приходится, т.е. за этим нужно следить. Kotlin оффициальный язык разработки под андроид. Это продукт не гуглб а джет брейнс, что и андроид студия. Гугл лишь принял котлин на замену яве. Согласен, можно начать с явы, но новые андроид-проекты на нем пишут... только легаси код. Теоретически любой язык смертен, но ближайшие 4 года проблем с котлин не предвижу. Flutter от Гугл пока сильно отсает.

Answer (score 1):

А как иначе если существует паттерн Singleton. Советую ознакомиться с ним.

Его идея проста. Создание единственного экземпляра для класса и хранение его ссылки в статической переменной. Так как утечек не  наблюдается и таковым минусом он не обладает советую присмотреться на этот паттерн и сделать выводы.

```
 public class Singleton {

  
  private static Singleton instance;
  private Singleton () {}

  public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
   if (instance == null) {
   instance = new Singleton();
  }
  return instance;
 }
}
```

Comment: И за что минус, может объясните? Или у вас есть что-то против Singeltona

Comment: Минус не мой, но мне кажется я понимаю логику минусующих: ваш текст не отвечает на заданный вопрос, сравните с соседним ответом. Вы могли бы оставить комментарий под вопросом, репутации у вас более чем достаточно. А после уже вполне могли начали минусовать за то, что вы перешли на личности и стали навешивать обидные ярлыки.

Comment: Комментарии для уточнения вопроса не мне вас учить. Мне вопрос ясен и ответ мой может быть очень короткий. Я не призываю принять ответ это право автора я туда не лезу. Минус не ваш вопросов по этому нет. Просто я считаю хорошим тоном объяснить минус если вам не нравится ответ.

Comment: Singleton и Application это вещи разные. Хотя дефакто Application и является единственным экземпляром класса Application он не является Singleton-ом. Второй момент, ваш вопрос не несет ответа. Как заметил @A.K это хорошо подходит под коммент, но не несет никакого ответа

Comment: Ребята я не выступаю как истиной в последней инстанции. Singelton и Application разные вещи, ну просто жесть, потерял дар речи, упал со стула. Я что где-то сказал или написал обратное? Вы что я написал что существует целый паттерн и там не говориться об утечки памяти или проблемах такого рода

Comment: Ну тогда странно выглядит ответ в котором советуют прочесть про Singlton если человек спрашивает про статический контекст в Application

Comment: Так лучше? Думаю что почитать было бы полезнее всё таки.

Comment: Вы предлагаете создать Application в вашем getInstance()?

Comment: Я дал ответ на вопрос. Что существует аналогичный паттерн. Реализовывать его буквально слово в слово я не вижу надобности. Это лишь пищя для размышления автору.

Comment: Да, спасибо за совет) Пользуюсь синглами при необходимости